# Show preview a file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, embed

It is that I need to send a preview of an image in a div in specific, taking the route of the image stored in the database and for this run a successful Ajax send the image.

```
success: function(respuesta) {
           var preview = document.getElementById("archivoRadicado").value = respuesta;
           $('#vistaPrevia').innerHTML = '<embed src="'+preview +'"/>';
       },
error: function(xhr,err) { 
           alert("Error");
       }
```

And the `<embed />` html control the path to receiving the route but I did not get anything, no errors or éxtito, I can do or have mistake?

This is where you should go div preview

```
<div id="vistaPrevia" style="width=100%; height:490px;">    

</div>
```

Comment: and your question is?

Comment: div why the image is not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to be sure you write CLEAN code. For starters, the following line is not valid.

```
<div id="vistaPrevia" style="width=100%; height:490px;">
```

Secondly, you're mixing up jquery and javascript. Stick to one, either jquery or javascript, since you have to initiate either one or the other, I believe, at least to my understanding, that you mustn't mix languages like this. If you decide to use jquery, change this line...

```
$('#vistaPrevia').innerHTML = '<embed src="'+preview +'"/>';
```

...to this

```
$('#vistaPrevia').html('<embed src="'+ preview +'"/>');
```

Hope this helps.